# what is going wrong here in Python Code while doing find and replace mechanism on a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

There are lot of files in a directory. I need to find a pattern and replace it with a new string in every file. I am able to do so, but when there are multiple occurrences of pattern in a file then code only replaces the last match not all the matches.

```
def find_and_replace(path):
only_files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
os.chdir(path)
pattern = '$$ENV$$'
final_string = ''

for i in iter(only_files):
    for n, line in enumerate(open(i)):
        if pattern in line:
            first_string = (line.split(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(i))[0])[0])
            second_string = first_string.split('.')[0]
            final_string = second_string.rsplit(' ', 1)[1]
            print final_string

    for newline in fileinput.FileInput(i, inplace=1):
        newline = newline.replace(final_string, "Mayank")
```

Can you please help me here.

Comment: What's in the files?

Comment: CREATE MULTISET TABLE $$ENV$$_ADWM_BFMDW.ANNAR ,NO FALLBACK  and likewise .ANNAR is file name so i am doing something like line.split(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(i))[0])[0] then taking string till first space is encountered and then calling replace method.

Comment: first correct your indentation in program...

Comment: Your code doesn't replace any matches.  Copy paste chopped off the last line of your code?  Also for-in already calls iter() on only_files, so you don't have to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> code only replaces the last match not all the matches.

Here is a skeleton of your code:

```
for fname in only_files:  #OUTER FOR-LOOP
    for line in open(fname):  #FIRST FOR-LOOP

            ...
            final_string = second_string.rsplit(' ', 1)[1]


    for newline in fileinput.FileInput(fname, inplace=1):  #SECOND FOR-LOOP
        newline = newline.replace(final_string, "Mayank")
```

1. The outer for loop gets a file name.
2. The first for loop assigns values to final_string over and over again as it steps through every line in the file.  After the for loop terminates, final_string contains a substring from the last line that contained the pattern.
3. The second for loop steps though every line in the file and does replacements for the value of final_string.  The value of final_string never changes in the second for loop.

You need to create an array of the matches, then use the second for loop to do the replacements.

I don't know who wrote that code, but it is way too convoluted for anyone to follow, so if you want to post on public forums and get help from people, then you need to aspire to write code more like this:

```
def find_and_replace(path):
    fnames = [
        fname for fname in os.listdir(path) 
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, fname))
    ]

    pattern = 'hello'
    os.chdir(path)

    for fname in fnames:
        with open(fname) as f:
            for line in f:
                if pattern in line:
                    name, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)

                    first_string = line.split(name)[0]
                    second_string = first_string.split('.')[0]
                    final_string = second_string.rsplit(' ', 1)[1]

            for newline in fi.FileInput(fname, inplace=1):
                newline = newline.replace(final_string, "Mayank")
                print(newline.rstrip())
```

In other words, use descriptive variable names--the variable name `i` is not appropriate for a filename; and do not try to do too much in one line of code.  Your os.path.splitext line is a disaster.

Also, because it is not obvious what substring you are extracting from a matching line, it would have been helpful to anyone trying to answer your question to have some samples of your files.

Comment: Thank You @7stud for making this as simple as it can get. Also, pointing out my wrong coding habit helped me understand what and where i need to improve.

Answer (score 0):

The following code just replaces a string.

Textfiles is the folder I created for testing.

```
import os
import fileinput
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
def find_and_replace(path):
    print(path)
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
    os.chdir(path)
    pattern = 'Salma'
    final_string = 'haris'

    for i in onlyfiles:

        # Read in the file
        with open(i, 'r') as file :
            filedata = file.read()

        # Replace the target string
        filedata = filedata.replace(pattern, final_string)

        # Write the file out again
        with open(i, 'w') as file:
            file.write(filedata)

find_and_replace("textfiles")
```

Comment: The following alone deserves a downvote: `for i in iter(onlyfiles)` because it shows a lack of fundamental python knowledge.